# How to start playing a playlist by clicking on a LinkLabel?

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have added the playlist names from a directory in a `ListBox` using `LinkLabel` at run time but now I want that when I click on the `LinkLabel` of that playlist, the playlist should run and play the songs.

I have no idea about how to give the path or link to the playlist in the link label and how to start playing it.

This is my code, `playlistviewbar` is a `ListBox`:

```
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Music\Playlists","*.wpl");
int yforlbl =5;
LinkLabel[] lblplayName = new LinkLabel[array1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    array1[i] = Path.GetFileName(array1[i]);

    lblplayName[i] = new LinkLabel();
    lblplayName[i].Text = array1[i];

    lblplayName[i].Location = new Point(0,yforlbl);          
    playlistviewbar.Controls.Add(lblplayName[i]);

    yforlbl += 23;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it in the for loop the double click event is like this and using `getbyname` mathod get the playlist and set it to current playlist

```
           lblplayName[i].DoubleClick += (senders, es) =>
           {

               LinkLabel label = (LinkLabel)senders;
               string PlayListFile = label.Text;

               try
               {

                   WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist list = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.getByName(PlayListFile).Item(0);

                   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = list;
               }
               catch
               {
                     //exception handling code
               }
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `LinkLabel`'s `Click` event handler, you can do something like this:

```
private void LinkLabel_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkLabel label = (LinkLabel)sender;
    string PlayListFile = label.Text;
    Process.Start(PlayListFile);
}
```

As `*.wpl` files are associated with Windows Media Player, it should start right away. You can find more info about the `Process.Start` method [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to embed the `MediaPlayer` control in your application, then you can have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i tried but it gives me error at `Process` and `Text`. i have also added assembly referance `System.Diagnostics.Process` but still gives error

Comment: still it is not working after clicking on the linklable it is not playling.. can you tell me how this work? and for what wmplayer.exe is there?

Comment: and i have used windows media player component in my player so i want to play playlist in that or to set it as media player's current playlist

Comment: @user1970036 I've edited the code above to use the file name only. It will use the default installation of WMP on the host...